# Inappbrowser issue in worklight hybrid application in android devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created worklight 6.2 hybrid application for android in which when user clicks on a button it has to open an Inappbrowser with external url. Below is the code I have used on click of a button:

```
$("#inapp").click(function(){
    window.open("https://xxxx.com","_blank","location=yes");
});
```

When I click on the button the application closes by displaying a pop up with an error message:

> Unfortunately, sampleApp stopped

This is happening only in android devices, in iOS it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Right now it looks like a defect in Worklight 6.2, it's being investigated. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks I will wait for your response. Mean while do we have any work around solution to fix this issue because I have my application release this week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with missing resources. The current workaround is to create a standalone Cordova 3.4 Android application with the Cordova Command Line Interface.

This will NOT be a replacement of your Worklight application - it  will allow you to generate the resources you are missing.

Workaround instructions:

--> Android Platform Guide:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

In the "Requirements and Support" section, follow the steps to include the Android SDK's tools and platform-tools directories in your PATH environment and to enable Java and Ant.

--> The Command-Line Interface:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%0AGuide

Follow the steps under "Prerequisites" then do the following commands:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
cordova build
```

--> Android Platform Guide: Follow the steps under "Open a Project in the SDK"

Now you can navigate to the files you need, which will be in:
\hello\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi

Copy the 3 ic_action PNG files into the \native\res\drawable-hdpi directory of your Worklight 6.2 project:

- ic_action_next_item.png
- ic_action_previous_item.png
- ic_action_remove.png

This should fix the issue and allow the application to run successfully.

Here is a technote on this issue: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21681060